# Vue.js Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, facebook, vue.js, vuejs2, facebook-login

I'm implementing a Facebook Login module which I have already imported and it works, but the trouble comes when I want to bind the response to an input. How could I achieve it? I'm kinda new with Vue.js

I'm [using this component](https://github.com/phanan/vue-facebook-signin-button)

FbLogin.vue

```
 <template>
  <fb-signin-button
    :params="fbSignInParams"
    @success="onSignInSuccess"
    @error="onSignInError">
    Ingresa con FB
  </fb-signin-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      fbSignInParams: {
        scope: 'email,user_likes',
        return_scopes: true,
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSignInSuccess (response) {
      FB.api('/me', dude => {
      console.log(`Good to see you, ${dude.name}.`)
      })
    },
    onSignInError (error) {
      console.log('Error de fBlogin', error)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Form.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
  .field
    pm-fb
    label.label
      h1.sutitle
      .control
        input.input.is-hovered(type="text" v-model="username" placeholder="Nombre(s)") 
        input.input.is-hovered(type="text" placeholder="Apellido Paterno")
</template>

<script>
import PmFb from '@/components/fBLogin.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    PmFb
  }
}
</script>
```

It displays the info in the console and that's what I want to bind to the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [string interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text) in Vue templates to display that message.

First, add a `data` property (e.g., named "message"):

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    };
  }
}
```

Then, add the `message` in your template, surrounded by curly brackets:

```
<template>
  <div>{{message}}</div>
</template>
```

When your Facebook login result is determined, set `this.message` to the desired message, similar to this:

```js
methods: {
  onSignInSuccess (response) {
    FB.api('/me', dude => {
      this.message = `Good to see you, ${dude.name}.`
    })
  },
  onSignInError (error) {
    this.message = `Error de fBlogin: ${error}`
  },
}
```